# Break a loop externally with the button that started the loop

Tags: python, while-loop, tkinter-button

I want to break a loop with the same button that I started the loop with.
For all intents and purposes, it does what I need it to, up until I click the button again. If I hit the button again, it crashes. Right now with the debug visual setup, I can hit q to break the loop. But down the road I obviously want to turn that off and just have it all go through the button instead.
I should also note that the button does not update unless the window is interacted with/moved. This goes for when the button is pushed. It doesn't crash until you move the window.

```py
def bttnup():
    global is_on
   
  #starts autoaccept
    if is_on:
        button.config(image = selected,
                    bg=selected_bg
                    )
        start()
        is_on = False

    else:
    #Stops autoaccept
        button.config(image = unselected,
                    bg=unselected_bg,
                    )
        is_on = True

#Object detection and keystroke
def start():
    while(True):
        screenshot = wincap.get_screenshot()
        points = vision_accept.find(screenshot, .325, 'rectangles')  
        if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            cv.destroyAllWindows()
            break

#Button
button = Button(window,
                image=unselected,
                command=bttnup)
button.pack()
```

I have also tried:

```py
def bttnup():
   #starts autoaccept
    if button['bg'] == 'unselected_bg':
        threading.join(1)
        button.config(image=selected,
                    bg=selected_bg
                    )
        start()
        return

    #Stops autoaccept
    if button['bg'] == 'selected_bg':
        threading.start()
        button.config(image = unselected,
                    bg=unselected_bg,
                    )
        return

#start object detection
def start():
    i = 1
    while button['bg'] == 'selected_bg':
        i = i+1
        # get an updated image of the game
        screenshot = wincap.get_screenshot()
        # screenshot = cv.resize(screenshot, (800, 600))
        points = vision_accept.find(screenshot, .325, 'rectangles')
        sleep(5)

#Button!
button = Button(window,
                image=unselected,
                command=lambda: bttnup())
```

Answer (score 0):

So I went and changed a majority of the code to use .after instead of using a while statement. Its not as clean looking, but it does what it needs to.

created a function for on, and one for off and have the button cycle when the button is fixed. when the on button is pushed it calls to the start function which then cycles every second.

```
# initialize the WindowCapture class
wincap = WindowCapture()

# Initialize the Vision class
vision_accept = Vision('accept.jpg')

#window parameters
window = Tk()
window.resizable(False, False)
window.title('AutoAccept')
unselected = PhotoImage(file='Button_unselected.png')
selected = PhotoImage(file='matching.png')
unselected_bg='white'
selected_bg='black'
is_on = True


def start_on():
    global is_on
   
   #starts autoaccept
    button.config(image = selected,
                bg=selected_bg,
                command = start_off
                )
    start()
    is_on = True

def start_off():
    global is_on
    button.config(image = unselected,
                bg=unselected_bg,
                command = start_on
                )
    is_on = False


#start object detection
def start():
    if is_on:

        # get an updated image of the game
        screenshot = wincap.get_screenshot()
        points = vision_accept.find(screenshot, .32, 'rectangles')

    window.after(500, start)

button = Button(window,
                image=unselected,
                command=start_on
                )

button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```